# Create a xml attribute

Tags: c#, xml

Structure class for XML file

Class CustomsMessage

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]

public partial class CUSTOMMESSAGES
{
    private CUSTOMMESSAGES_HEADER HEADER_FIELD;     
public CUSTOMMESSAGES_HEADER Header
    {
        get { return this.HEADER_FIELD; }
        set { this.HEADER_FIELD = value; }
    }
}
```

//Class Header

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class CUSTOMMESSAGES_HEADER
{
    private string SubmitToCustoms_Field;
    private string SubmissionType_Field;
    
    public string SubmitToCustoms
    {
        get { return this.SubmitToCustoms_Field; }
        set { this.SubmitToCustoms_Field = value; }
    }
    
    [XmlAttribute("SubmissionType")]
    public string SubmissionType
    {

        get { return this.SubmissionType_Field; }
        set { this.SubmissionType_Field = value; }
    }
}
```

Another class to build a XML file

```
public string GeneralXML1()
{
    CUSTOMMESSAGES CustomMessage = new CUSTOMMESSAGES();
    CUSTOMMESSAGES_HEADER HEADER = new CUSTOMMESSAGES_HEADER();

    HEADER.SubmitToCustoms = "Y";
    HEADER.SubmissionType = "Original";         

    tmp = XmlExtension.Serialize<CUSTOMMESSAGES>(CustomMessage);
}
```

XML file i want

```
<CustomsMessage>
       <Header>
           <SubmitToCustoms SubmissionType="Original">Y</SubmitToCustoms>
       </Header>
</CustomsMessage>
```

How can i add an attribute into SubmitToCustoms tag ? I had tried XmlRoot but it doesn't work. Need help and thank you

Comment: how are you writing your xml?

Comment: what i show you is a part of it. I made class like that with values inside and in the another class i use XmlExtension.Serialize to build a xml file. Sorry for bad grammer.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I did change the question. If you need anything just tell me.

Comment: `XmlExtension.Serialize` is it custom code? If so please include that as well into the question.

Comment: No it's the library, it's from System.Xml.Serialize.. It help craft all value into a XML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get the desired output requires some slight modifications on your classes.
(I've used auto-properties for the sake of brevity.)

```cs
[XmlRoot("CustomsMessage")]
public class CUSTOMMESSAGES
{
    [XmlArray("Header")]
    [XmlArrayItem("SubmitToCustoms")]
    public CUSTOMMESSAGES_HEADER[] Header { get; set; }
}

public class CUSTOMMESSAGES_HEADER
{
    [XmlText]
    public string SubmitToCustoms { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("SubmissionType")]
    public string SubmissionType { get; set; }
}
```

- With `XmlRoot` I've specified the top-level entity
- With `XmlArray` I've specified the middle-level entity
- With `XmlArrayItem` I've specified the bottom-level entity

  - I've changed type of `Header` from `CUSTOMMESSAGES_HEADER` to `CUSTOMMESSAGES_HEADER[]` to align for the desired output.
- With `XmlText` I've specified the value of the bottom-level entity
- With `XmlAttribute` I've specified an attribute for the bottom-level entity.

Let's play with your sample data:

```cs
CUSTOMMESSAGES CustomMessage = new CUSTOMMESSAGES();
CUSTOMMESSAGES_HEADER HEADER = new CUSTOMMESSAGES_HEADER();

CustomMessage.Header =  new [] { HEADER };
HEADER.SubmitToCustoms = "Y";
HEADER.SubmissionType = "Original";
```

**NOTE**: You have to explicitly connect message and header. This is missing from your sample code.

Now let's call the serializer:

```cs
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CUSTOMMESSAGES));
using StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();
serializer.Serialize(textWriter, CustomMessage);
var tmp = textWriter.ToString();
```

The output will be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<CustomsMessage xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <SubmitToCustoms SubmissionType="Original">Y</SubmitToCustoms>
    </Header>
</CustomsMessage>
```

In order to get rid of the namespaces and the xml declaration we need to use the following code:

```cs
var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("", "");

var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true};
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CUSTOMMESSAGES));

await using StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();
using var writer = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings);
serializer.Serialize(writer, CustomMessage, ns);
var tmp = textWriter.ToString();
```

Now, the output will be as expected.

```xml
<CustomsMessage>
    <Header>
        <SubmitToCustoms SubmissionType="Original">Y</SubmitToCustoms>
    </Header>
</CustomsMessage>
```

---

**UPDATE**: How to reduce the number of attributes

### Alternative #1

To reduce the number of attributes the hierarchy and the names of the classes should resemble to the XML as much as possible:

```cs
public class CustomsMessage
{
    public Header Header { get; set; }
}

public class Header
{
    public SubmitToCustoms SubmitToCustoms { get; set; }
}

public class SubmitToCustoms
{
    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("SubmissionType")]
    public string SubmissionType { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see with this approach we have reduced the quantity of attributes from 5 to 2.

Now, the sample object creation looks like this:

```cs
var CustomMessage = new CustomsMessage
{
    Header = new Header
    {
        SubmitToCustoms = new SubmitToCustoms
        {
            SubmissionType = "Original",
            Value = "Y"
        }
    }
};
```

### Alternative #2

We can get rid of all of the attributes if we switch from **declarative** based serialization to **imperative**.

```cs
var type = CustomMessage.Header.SubmitToCustoms.SubmissionType;
var value = CustomMessage.Header.SubmitToCustoms.Value;
var xml = 
    new XElement("CustomsMessage", 
        new XElement("Header", 
            new XElement("SubmitToCustoms", 
                new XAttribute("SubmitType", type),
                new XText(value))));
tmp = xml.ToString();
```

Here we are making use of the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace.

As you can see your data model is independent from the serialization.

Comment: First of all thank you for helping me solve my problems, what i show you now is a part of my project and there are more objects and attribute behind so i still need declare root as a Array even have more than 5 attributes ?

Comment: @DuVoQuoc I've extended my answer with other alternatives please check them.

Comment: Thank you for your helping !! I appreciate it.